# In ASP.NET Core 6 Razor Pages how do I CRUD the Users and Roles?

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I have followed this monumental tutorial [Create an ASP.NET Core web app with user data protected by authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which gave me a good oversight for Authorization.

However I still can't find a way to simply CRUD Roles and Users. Anywhere! The best I have seen are tutorials in MVC on making a list of users and roles. But that conflicts with my existing program.

There are a number of old tutorials, some still on the MS website, for MVC, webforms, etc, but nothing for Core 6 Razor pages.

Is there a CRUD of Core 6 ASPNetRoles and ASPNetUsers? If not why not? Is it a security issue? Does everyone roll their own? Is it so easy that I just don't get it?

Edit: As an update, I found this excellent resource https://github.com/mikebrind/Razor-Pages-In-Action/tree/main/Chapter10 if anyone else is looking for guidence.

Answer (score 0):

They still exist, except much less is included in the template.

If you start with the .NET 6 Templates ex;

> MVC - `dotnet new web --auth individual`
> Razor Pages - `dotnet new razor --auth individual`
> Blazor - `dotnet new blazor --auth individual`

It will kick you out a template with: Bootstrap CSS, Entity Framework and a database with the Identity Library and a Razor Class Library for the Register and sign in, etc.

From here, you are provided abstractions like `IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole` and base classes like `RoleManager`. There aren't any implementations or frontend code provided out of the box.

These abstractions give you the flexibility to opt-in, and tailor to suit your organizational requirements. CRUD is rather simple and will take very little effort to implement.

> Reference Source for CRUD RoleManager in MVC -> https://github.com/procodeguide/Sample.Identity.Roles/blob/main/ProCodeGuide.Sample.Blog/Controllers/RoleController.cs

Comment: Thanks Adam, I tried that one, but it is core 3, and MVC. I only got it partially working.